# In PHP8 php-fpm unable to Turn on CURL

Tags: curl, php-curl, php-8

Ubuntu OS / NGinx / PHP-FPM

So... curl is located at /usr/bin/curl

Have gone into the php.ini and uncommented the extension=curl

Have installed and reinstalled

***php8.0-curl***

Just everytime I run a curl_init says there is no curl avaiable in the installation.

am I missing a step somewhere?

-r

Comment: what do you get from `php --ini` ? chances are you're editing the *wrong* php.ini